# How to prevent the installation of third-party AVs for a domain using GPOs?

Tags: group-policy, wmi, anti-virus

Our organization uses a particular AV that we manage, but we currently have no way to enforce users not to install any other AVs, which has started to become an issue. I know windows can typically detect what AV software it has installed through WMI (as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp). Is there a way we could use GPOs or similar to enforce this?

Comment: Detecting AV software and preventing it from being installed are two different things. You're probably going to have to use AppLocker to prevent it from being installed. That being said, this is a serious "people" problem that you're trying to solve with a technical solution. You need to solve the "people" problem.